# ESDoc puts all of my module methods under one heading, not under each file, how do I change this behavior?

Tags: javascript, documentation

In my project, I have a helpers folder with a few things...

```
src/
src/helpers
src/helpers/astring.js
src/helpers/amath.js
src/helpers/adate.js
```

All of these are modules with private and exported methods. When generating documentation with esdoc, I have a hundred or so methods under a heading of "helpers" all mixed up. I have no idea what is a string method, a math method, or a date method.

Any thoughts on how to make this more manageable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EsDoc, that's just the way it works. However, typhonrt just release (7 hrs ago) a plugin for esdoc that turns the navigation area into a collapsable list representing directory and file structure.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/esdoc-plugin-enhanced-navigation

This solves the problem.